# How to use db indexing to create unique node (or get existing node handle) in neo4j through Java code?

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I want to create nodes having persons but don't want to duplicate them. For every insertion, I get two entities among which I have to make a relationship, so it may happen that none, one or both are already in my db. So, how to use indexing and deal with the situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a manual page on this topic

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/transactions-unique-nodes.html